# Metric and connection on virtual bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Let $E=[E^+]-[E^-]$ be an element of the Grothendieck group $K(X)$ of a compact Kahler manifold $X$.

Does it exist a way to define more "geometric" structures on $E\in K(X)$ such that a Hermitian metric and a connection?

Comment: The arithmetic Grothendieck group (see work by Gillet-Soulé) might be going in the direction you want.